# Sidebar Widget Misaligned on Category Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm re-posting the same problem, but I'm better defining the issues.

Basically, I was trying to limit the number of articles that appeared on my index page - however, it seems that I managed to break any CATEGORY page that I create.

For example, if you go to http://www.invisiblejungle.com, the "Recent Posts" section that pulls from the category "Radio Shows" appears just fine.

However, if you click Radio Shows in the navigation bar, which is a category, it throws the sidebar widget to the bottom of the page, and distorts each of the individual articles.

EDIT:

I've discovered that the issue is definitely in loop.php when it retrieves the posts.

```
<?php  
/**
 * The loop for displaying multiple posts (blog, search, categories, tags, etc).
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Debut
 * @since Debut 2.0
 *
 */
?>

    <?php   if( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
        /**
         * Page Header
         *
         */
        locate_template( 'includes/page-header.php', true ); ?>

        <?php   while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'entry' ) ?>>

                <?php 
                /**
                 * Entry Thumbnail
                 *
                 */
                locate_template( 'includes/entry-thumbnail.php', true, false ); ?>


                <?php
                /**
                 * Entry Header
                 *
                 */
                locate_template( 'includes/entry-header.php', true, false ); ?>


                <?php
                /**
                 * Entry Content/Summary
                 *
                 */
                if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Check if this is an Archives and Search page ?>

                    <div class="entry-summary">

                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                        <a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php c7s_the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Read More &rarr;', 'framework' ); ?></a>

                    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

                <?php else : // If not Archives or Search page ?>

                    <div class="entry-content">

                        <?php global $more; $more = 0; // Needed for more tag to work ?>

                        <?php the_content( __( 'Read More &rarr;', 'framework' ) ); // Show content ?>

                        <?php do_action( 'get_page_links' ); // Show page links (custom function to wp_link_pages() - functions/theme-helpers.php ?>

                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                <?php endif; // End Archive and Search page check ?>

            </article><!-- #post-## -->

            <?php 
            /**
             * Entry Comments
             *
             */
            comments_template( '', true ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end posts loop ?>
      <?php else : // If there are not any posts ?>

        <?php
        /**
         * Page Header
         *
         */
        locate_template( 'includes/page-header.php', true ); ?>


        <?php
        /**
         * Archives
         *
         */
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'archives' ); ?>


    <?php endif; // end loop ?>

        <?php
    /**
     * Pagination
     *
     */
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : // Check for pages ?>

        <div id="nav-below" class="pagenavi">

            <?php if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) : // Check for WP Page Navi Plugin ?>

                <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span>' . __( ' Older posts', 'framework' ) ); ?></div>

                <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts ', 'framework' ) . '<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ); ?></div>

            <?php endif; // End WP Page Navi plugin check ?>


        </div><!-- #nav-below -->

    <?php endif; // end page check ?>

</section><!-- #entry-container -->
```

Comment: Can you list the files in your theme folder. It appears the category pages and the search pages are doing this.

Comment: There are several: 
Comments
(comments.php)
Footer
(footer.php)
theme-helpers.php
theme-metabox.php
theme-tinymce.php
theme-widgets.php
Theme Functions
(functions.php)
Header
(header.php)
home.php
announcement.php
archives.php
entry-header.php
entry-thumbnail.php
page-header.php
Main Index Template
(index.php)
loop-archives.php
loop-featured.php
loop-hero.php
loop-singular.php
loop.php
options-announcement.php
options-featured.php
options-footer.php
options-general.php
options-hero.php
options-instant-view.php
options-logo-icons.php
options-menus.php

Comment: options-plugins.php
options-save-the-web.php
options-social-media.php
options-thank-you.php
options-theme-styles.php
options.php
Page Template
(page.php)
Search Form
(searchform.php)
sidebar-footer.php
Sidebar
(sidebar.php)
Single Post
(single.php)
Archives Page Template
(template-archives.php)
Centered Page Template
(template-centered.php)
Full Width Page Template
(template-full.php)
Custom Post Page Page Template
(template-post-page.php)

Sorry that I don't have a very convenient way to do this in the comments...

I'll post it in the main file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="main-container" role="main">

<section id="main">    

<section id="entry-container" role="contentinfo">////   


    <header class="entry page-header">

    ....
    ....
    ....            


    </ul><!-- #sidebar -->

</section><!-- #sidebar-container -->

</section><!-- #main -->////



    <div class="clearfix"><!-- nothing to see here --></div>

</div>
```

The lines I put //// after are what fixes the html. Please post the php from one of your working pages so I can compare.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably going to be in your archive.php.

According to the Wordpress Template Hierarchy, Wordpress looks in order of these files to use for your category pages:

```
 category-{slug}.php - If the category's slug were news, WordPress
 would look for category-news.php category-{id}.php - If the category's
 ID were 6, WordPress would look for category-6.php category.php
 archive.php 
 index.php
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

So most likely your error is located in that file. What you could do to fix this though, is to going into a file that is working very well. Such as your `page.php` and copy all its contents into `archive.php`. Be sure to backup first!